# using cut on a line having multiple instances of the same delimiter - unix

Tags: bash, unix, cut

I am trying to write a generic script which can have different file name inputs.

This is just a small part of my bash script.

for example, lets say folder 444-55 has 2 files

```
qq.filter.vcf
ee.filter.vcf
```

I want my output to be -

```
qq
ee
```

I tried this and it worked -

```
ls /data2/delivery/Stack_overflow/1111_2222_3333_23/secondary/444-55/*.filter.vcf | sort | cut -f1 -d "." | xargs -n 1 basename
```

But lets say I have a folder like this -

```
/data2/delivery/Stack_overflow/de.1111_2222_3333_23/secondary/444-55/*.filter.vcf
```

My script's output would then be

```
de
de
```

How can I make it generic?

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this in a script will "cut" it:

```
for i in /data2/delivery/Stack_overflow/1111_2222_3333_23/secondary/444-55/*.filter.vcf
do
   basename "$i" | cut -f1 -d.
done | sort
```

advantages:

- it does not parse the output of `ls`, which is [frowned upon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19574307/parsing-ls-not-recommended)
- it cuts *after* having applied the `basename` treatment, and the `cut` ignores the full path.
- it also sorts last so it's guaranteed to be sorted according to the prefix

Answer (score 1):

Just move the basename call earlier in the pipeline:

```
printf "%s\n" /data2/delivery/Stack_overflow/1111_2222_3333_23/secondary/444-55/*.filter.vcf |
  xargs -n 1 basename |
  sort |
  cut -f1 -d.
```

Comment: would `echo` be enough instead of `printf` ? answer is good because it avoids a `for` loop.

Comment: No, because you need the filenames to be on separate lines so that xargs can read them

Comment: I get it. Nice trick. BTW why do we have to sort something that the shell already sorts? Maybe some exotic filesystems issue the files in random order (clearcase MVFS), but on standard filesystems it seems useless.

Comment: Yes, that's true.