# How to make a `ls | greep foo` with powershell?

Tags: powershell, file-listing

I am doing a PowerShell script, I want to show at the terminal a list of the files like I do in bash: `ls | grep "foo.sh"`

I tried to make:

```
dir | select-string -pattern "foo.sh"
```

but that looks *inside* the files, I want to filter by the name. I also tried

```
get-childItem | select-string -pattern "foo.sh"
```

but I have the same problem. `Text-Path` isn't working because I need a list of the files.

Comment: [never use `ls | grep`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/44425)

Comment: powershell is an object oriented language, everything literally is an object, if you want to filter objects use `Where-Object` and leave `Select-String` for matching strings.

Comment: Two asides: `dir` is simply an _alias_ of `Get-ChildItem`, so your two commands are equivalent. Both `grep` and `Select-String` interpret their patterns as _regexes_ by default, so to match a _literal_ `.` you'd have to either use `'foo\.sh'` or use `grep -F 'foo.sh'` / `Select-String -SimpleMatch -Pattern 'foo.sh'`

Comment: Does `Get-ChildItem -Filter '*foo.sh*'` produce what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash [you should never pipe `ls` output to other commands](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19574307/995714), and the same applies to PowerShell in this case<sup>1</sup>. Even worse, since PowerShell cmdlets return **objects**, not strings, piping `Get-ChildItem` output to `Select-String` makes absolutely zero sense because the object needs to be converted to string somehow, which may not return a useful string to match

The `-Path` parameter in [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.2) already receives a pattern, just use it. That means to get the list of files whose names contain `foo.sh` just run

```
Get-ChildItem -Path *foo.sh*
```

or

```
ls *foo.sh*
```

In bash you do the same, and `ls *foo.sh*` returns more correct results than `ls | grep foo.sh`, and also faster. For listing `foo.sh` only obviously you just do `ls foo.sh` in both bash and PowerShell

For better performance in PowerShell you can also use

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *foo.sh*
```

which filters out names right from the [Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_providers?view=powershell-7.2) level, which calls the Win32 API directly with the pattern

---

<sup>1</sup>Unlike bash, in PowerShell due to the object-oriented nature, sometimes you do pipe `ls` outputs to other commands for further processing, because you can operate on the original objects instead of strings so it'll still work for any files with special names or properties. For example

```
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object { $_.Parent -eq "abc" -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date) }
```

Comment: Good information in general, but note that piping Get-ChildItem output to Select-String _does_ make sense, because it is _special-cased_: it causes Select-String to search the input files' _contents_ - which is indeed what the OP accidentally ran into.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `-Name` flag:

```
Get-ChildItem -Name | Select-String -Pattern "foo.sh"
```

Comment: That avoids the original problem, but it seems like overkill in this case, given that `Get-ChildItem *foo.sh*` or `Get-ChildItem -Filter *foo.sh*` would do. That said, if you need sophisticated, regex-based name matching, this approach may be called for.

Comment: and it'll return files like foolsh, foodsh which may not be expected